# Automatically Updating a Google Sheets Table inside Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have several Google Sheets tables inside a Googles Slides presentation that I would like to keep automatically updated.

Is there a of triggering the new "Update All" feature in Scripts? Or is there some other feature that would do it?

Note - I know there is a way of automatically updating Sheets Charts in a Slides presentation, but I specifically need a way to automatically update Sheets Tables. Recently at least this wasn't possible but I am hoping things have changed in light of the new "Update All" feature.

Comment: FYI - there's a [Zap](https://zapier.com/apps/google-sheets/integrations/google-slides/13919/refresh-charts-on-a-google-slides-presentation-when-rows-are-updated-on-google-sheets) that does this :)

Comment: There is a feature request for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/64027131. Give it a start to increase visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
function myFunction() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    var slide = slides[i];
    var charts = slide.getSheetsCharts();
    for (var j = 0; j < charts.length; j++) {
      var chart = charts[j];
      chart.refresh();
    }
  }
}
```

<strike>I'm using an `onOpen` trigger but you're free to replace it with a normal function or another trigger ex: onEdit(e) and it would virtually update every single chart in all the slides.</strike>

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi thanks but this solution only refreshes charts. for some reason there  doesn't seem to be a scripts way to refresh tables

Comment: Have you tried this? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7009814#update_charts

Comment: yes I had already come across this. it's not quite enough for what I need it to do, but we're probably one update away from it...

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Update Slide Data', 'updateSlide')
      .addToUi();
}

function updateSlide() {
  try {
    var presentationIds = [
      '1GSxCvZnqZCems1QqnswLABAvWSJjbBJ-ZdnJdFbvduE',
      '1KhbuhiqiQNX9YthNAmpK0h8zkzexER2-D8yM4Jq31O4',
      '1-wKtlMJUaPRHipXHKz4DpfPgsgDQzC33B-MiagKRdKw',
      '1M2FHjJjcWE-EETAvqqVZk4yH2rw90OleL3FuSsKa6RI',
      '1od9SwaYTAeynqlXCKV2d-bp31fXvD1ZtNADfsvPQ8rM',
      '1pNkgFcQve_SmL3TSot49adA0F8FYOMqgksZjp3nod-s'
    ];

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1SPgjIpT2wVUWheRQ3rTEN4aWOxYK-X0HVoq3f33juSM');
    
    // Dummy operation to force the sheet to refresh.
    var dummyCell = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1');
    var dummyValue = dummyCell.getValue();
    dummyCell.setValue(dummyValue);

    for (var i = 0; i < presentationIds.length; i++) {
      var presentationId = presentationIds[i];
      var slides = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides();
      
      // Fetch the data for each presentation
      var dataRange = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('e3:e' + (i == 0 ? 6 : 4)); // Adjust range based on presentation
      var data = dataRange.getValues();

      // Update tables on all slides in the presentation
      for (var j = 0; j < slides.length; j++) {
        var tables = slides[j].getTables();
        for (var k = 0; k < tables.length; k++) {
          var table = tables[k];
          updateTable(table, data);
        }
      }

      Logger.log("Slides updated at: " + new Date() + " for Presentation ID: " + presentationId);
    }
    // MailApp.sendEmail('cchambers@acs-schools.com', 'Slides Updated', 'The Google Slides have been updated.');

  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error: ' + error.toString());
    MailApp.sendEmail('cchambers@acs-schools.com', 'Slides Update Failed', 'The Google Slides update failed. Error: ' + error.toString());
    MailApp.sendEmail('cchambers@acs-schools.com', 'Automated message from Colin, day Slide failed to up date.', 'The Google Slides update failed. Error: ' + error.toString());
  }
}

// Function to update tables
function updateTable(table, data) {
  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[0].length; col++) {
      var cellValue = data[row][col];
      var formattedValue = cellValue instanceof Date ? Utilities.formatDate(cellValue, "GMT", "HH:mm") : cellValue.toString();
      table.getCell(row, col).getText().setText(formattedValue);
    }
  }
}

enter code here
```